# How to do something before object destruction in Dart?

Tags: dart, destructor, angular-dart

In Java we can do something like override finalize(), in C++ we can do something like ~Someclass(),

But How can I do it in dart, I read the doc in https://www.dartlang.org/ but did not find answers.

Comment: If you are using angular-dart, DetachAware can help you. Implement your component from DetachAware and override detach method.

Answer (score 33):

This is not supported. There is nothing like a destructor in Dart.
JS garbage collector doesn't provide a way to implement this.
See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/20490161/217408 and https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/3691

Answer (score 6):

Dart now provides [finalizers](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Finalizer-class.html), as of Dart 2.17.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is relevant, but Flutter provides dispose method, which works similar to a deconstructor, it lets you dispose any object or instance methods, e.g.

- Subscription (which your don' t want to after your page is gone)

just override this method after your build method to dispose any methods.